# Run java application from eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have to try Push Notifications. **I follow all the instructions** from [this](http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/) link.
Now I have to run App.java(It's server part, not client part, so is not an android application), but I have a problem. 
When I run as java application, Eclipse show me an error window
saying:"Selection does not contain a main type".

How can I fix this problem?

This is App.java class:

```
package com.hmkcode;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.hmkcode.vo.Content;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
          System.out.println( "Sending POST to GCM" );

          String apiKey = "AIzaSyC..........";
          Content content = createContent();

          POST2GCM.post(apiKey, content);
    }

    public static Content createContent(){

        Content c = new Content();

        c.addRegId("APA91bE8R9nR.........");
        c.createData("Test Title", "Test Message");

        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its an android application check http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-eclipse.html how to run an android application from eclipse.

Comment: Either you want to run a Java Application or an Android Application. Decide and if it is a Java app then everyone requires `public static void main(String[] args){...}` to run.

Comment: I have only "run as java application " option.  The client it's an android application, the server(I have to run this class from server project) it's java application